# Release Azure Data Factory project using VSTS Release

Tags: visual-studio, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to create an Azure Data Factory project in Visual Studio rather than create an Azure Data Factory directly in the Azure portal. The reason why is that I wish to have the project in source control since it is a team project and for the sake of having it backed up.

I want to use Visual Studio Team Services to automate the Build and Release processes for the aforementioned Azure Data Factory project. The Build process is straightforward; it will be an MSBuild run on the solution. However, I am unsure how to go about the Release definition. Is there a task/set of tasks or a different method that will allow me to deploy my Azure Data Factory project into Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy Azure Data Factory using PowerShell.

1. Add Azure PowerShell step/task to build/release definition
2. Simple script:

Code:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "[ProjectFolder]" -filter "LinkedService*")
{
  New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "SampleFactory" -Name $file.BaseName -File $file.FullName -Force | Format-List
}
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "[ProjectFolder]" -filter "DataSet*")
{
 New-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "SampleFactory" -Name $file.BaseName -File $file.FullName -Force | Format-List
}
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "[ProjectFolder]" -filter "Pipeline*")
{
 New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "SampleFactory" -Name $file.BaseName -File $file.FullName -Force | Format-List
}
```

More information, you can refer to this article: [Deploy Azure Data Factory using PowerShell](http://eatcodelive.com/2016/01/18/deploy-azure-data-factory-using-powershell/).

Comment: When I create an Azure PowerShell task and use the above query in it, I get the following error: `Credential operation error: The authorization code for your  linked service is invalid to generate authentication token. Please reauthorize this linked service with an account that has access to your  resource and promptly redeploy the linked service.` The deployment works, but it says "Provisioning Failed" in the Azure portal and I have to manually click the "Authorize" button in the "Author and Deploy" section. I know there is C# code to automate this, but how can I integrate with my PowerShell?

Comment: @brodskyb What're the results if you build azure data factory by using PowerShell and Rest API manually?

Comment: @brodskyb Links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline-using-powershell  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline-using-rest-api

Comment: Do you mean that I should:
1. Create the ADF using PowerShell
2. Create the linked services/data sets/etc. in Visual Studio
3. Use Azure PowerShell in Release definition to deploy changes that are made to the files in Visual Studio
? Because if I create the ADF using PowerShell, how will I be able to develop the various components of the ADF in Visual Studio for source control?

Comment: @brodskyb No, I just want to know, could you build data factory by using PowerShell or Rest API manually? Just make a test and post the result here.