# How do we deploy ADF project from VSTS release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have ADF project setup in my local visual studio. I am able to push the code to remote repository in VSTS via CI pipeline. However, I am not sure how to configure release definition for ADF to deploy the same to existing data factory in Azure portal. Any suggestions will be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy Azure Data Factory by using Azure PowerShell step/task.

More information, you can refer to this thread: [Release Azure Data Factory project using VSTS Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730210/release-azure-data-factory-project-using-vsts-release)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I am successful in creating an azure powershell task by following the steps mentioned in the link and VSTS says deployment is successful but when I look at the data factory in Azure portal, it is not updated. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: @vigneshsrinivasan What're detail code and build log? What's the result if you run powershell on local machine manually?

Comment: When I run the powershell script, I get authorization issue. Do you know how to generate authorization token and session id programatically? I looked at a reference -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-usql-activity. But how do I integrate this with ADF project? please help

Comment: What's the detail error message? Do you run Add-AzureRmAccount or Login-AzureRmAccount script?

Comment: I run Add-AzureRmAccount at the beginning. This is the error message I get- New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService : Credential operation error: The authorization code for your  linked service is
invalid to generate authentication token. Please reauthorize this linked service with an account that has access to your resource and promptly redeploy the linkedservice

Comment: @vigneshsrinivasan How do you configure the azure powershell task and Azure Service Endpoint?