# Azure Data Factory Secure Publish

Tags: c#, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory Visual Studio Project within a GitHub repository, and as part of the configuration I have a few linked services, for example, one for an Asure SQL Database, Azure Blob and one for an Azure Batch, all of these linked services have a connection string or account key.

I used The Secure Publish aproach described here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/ADFSecurePublish

so, i can do a manualy manualy publish, but i want continious integration using appveyor for the build and after the build i want to run a script to automatically deploy my project to azure.

How can i do a "secure publish" with this approach, how can i use my keyvault's key from the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple answer is that you can't (currently).

I would however argue that once you have manually and securely published your ADF linked services why would you need to redeployment them? Old and new things can just use existing linked services.

Agree with the continuous integration idea. But would suggest this only applies to datasets, pipelines and activities. In which case use PowerShell to deal with this. See:

[Release Azure Data Factory project using VSTS Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730210/release-azure-data-factory-project-using-vsts-release)

As a side note, we currently have bigger problems in that ADF projects aren't event supported in the latest version of Visual Studio. Never mind worrying about CI with Secure Publishing :-)

Maybe post this request on the Microsoft user voice feedback site.

Or

Maybe wait to see what the next version of ADF has to offer.