# Deployment of Azure Data Factory version2 Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

What are the different ways to deploy the adf v2 pipelines on different environment. What can be the best approach to do fast, repeatable, reliable deployments of pipelines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in v2 there isn't really any best practices to follow as the development tools are still in private preview. But as somebody with access to the new dev UI and can offer assurances that the things you seek are coming. Probably later this month, but I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to repeatability and automation of your deployments, you have 2 options:

1. Script the deployments using PowerShell. This works like the deployment of the [data factory v1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730210/release-azure-data-factory-project-using-vsts-release/41737184#41737184), but you'll have to use the v2 commandlets, and you'll have to add triggers. You can use PowerShell to parametrize connections to linked services and other environment specific values.
2. Deploy using ARM templates and run it from a PowerShell / TFS deployment. [You can find an example here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-data-factory-v2-blob-to-blob-copy). In this case it is possible to use ARM template parameters to parameterize connections to linked services and other environment specific values.